# Is there a way to set an auto-filter? If not, I'd like to request one

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, filtering, top-questions

I noticed tonight in Programmers that the first two pages of newest top questions (and a substantial proportion of the actives) are all negative, and many are on hold for being way off-topic or ambiguous or just copied homework problems.  The fact that these questions remain at the top of the top questions list kind of defeats the purpose of the top questions page if you want to use it to answer questions.

I've seen that there is a way to search for questions with a minimum score, which is okay, but the search results are much less useful because the questions don't have as nearly much information listed with them as they do on the top questions page (no tags, no information on answers, etc.).

It seems like there should be a way to auto-filter crap out of your top questions without running a search, and maybe there should even be a default filter for it.  I'm curious if such a feature exists, but judging by the responses to meta's questions on the search feature, I'm guessing it doesn't.  So if I'm barking up a dry tree (pardon my metaphor mixing), I'd like to propose it.

If this is the wrong place for such a thing, please let me know and I'll remove my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> no tags, no information on answers, etc.

Really? When I perform [this search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0..%20is%3aq) I get the newest questions with the score at least 0 and all the information you mentioned:

[image: sample]

You can set this as your filter for the site by simply bookmarking the search URL. (This is what I do for all SE sites that I participate on; I never open the front page.) The available parameters are documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Ah!  I didn't use is:q so I wasn't actually seeing questions.  I just assumed the search results were questions.  Thank you!